# Multi-array with one output

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code, which currently does not working properly. How can I make it working?  My wish is to make output like one string (of course I know how to "convert" array to string):

> words altered, added, and removed to make it

Code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$text = explode(" ", strip_tags("words altered added and removed to make it")); 
$stack = array();

$words = array("altered", "added", "something"); 
foreach($words as $keywords){
   $check = array_search($keywords, $text);
   if($check>(-1)){
     $replace = " ".$text[$check].","; 
   $result = str_replace($text[$check], $replace, $text);
    array_push($stack, $result);
   }
}

print_r($stack);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => words
            [1] =>  altered,
            [2] => added
            [3] => and
            [4] => removed
            [5] => to
            [6] => make
            [7] => it
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => words
            [1] => altered
            [2] =>  added,
            [3] => and
            [4] => removed
            [5] => to
            [6] => make
            [7] => it
        )
)
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: you can use implode(' ',$stack[0]);

Comment: implode outputs only first array result

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: words altered, added, and removed to make it

Comment: have you tried implode function in php, it can convert array into string.

Comment: It would be a much better question if you would explain in words what you hope to do,such as: _Replace words in `$text` with words in `$words` and add a comma._  If that's what you want.

Comment: better to add sample input and desired output for that input in description.

Comment: @Faraz:  I see that, but maybe also a statement of why the output is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more explanation it's as simple as this:

```
$text  = strip_tags("words altered added and removed to make it"); 
$words = array("altered", "added", "something"); 

$result = $text;
foreach($words as $word) {
    $result = str_replace($word, "$word,", $result);
}
```

- Don't explode your source string
- Loop the words and replace the word with the word and added comma

Or abandoning the loop approach:

```
$text   = strip_tags("words altered added and removed to make it"); 
$words  = array("altered", "added", "something"); 

$result = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $words).')/', '$1,', $text);
```

- Create a pattern by imploding the words on the alternation (OR) operator `|`
- Replace found word with the word `$1` and a comma

Comment: Thank you SIR! Thats real answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `iterator`

```
// Array with your stuff.
$array = [];

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach($iterator as $value) {
  echo $v, " ";
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion does not working, please next time run the code before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach should work with a few modifications. Loop over the words in the exploded string instead. For each one, if it is in the array of words to modify, add the comma. If not, don't. Then the modified (or not) word goes on the stack.

```
$text = explode(" ", strip_tags("words altered added and removed to make it")); 
$words = array("altered", "added", "something"); 

foreach ($text as $word) {
    $stack[] = in_array($word, $words) ? "$word," : $word;
}
```